Python sub-class that is inherited by multiple classes
Currently I have a class-definition that looks something like this:
class cls_A:

    def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3):
        x = a1 + a2
        y = a2 + a3
        self.__plot__(self)
    # some attributes
    # some methods

    def __plot__(self, parent):
        class plot_fns:
            # plot functions
            def plot1(self):
               plt.plot(parent.x, parent.y)
        self.plot = plot_fns()

A = cls_A(a1, a2, a3)

I do this based on the answer in How to access outer class from an inner class?. This means that I can use the sub-object `plot' to conveniently plot the parameters of the object A. For example:
A.plot.plot1()

Now, I have a similar definition of cls_B, and its instance B. cls_A and cls_B do not have all the same attributes, but the attributes that are related to plotting are the same. Therefore, I would like to have the same sub-object plot functionality for object B. Currently, I have a repeated definition of the function _plot_ in cls_B.
class cls_B:

    def __init__(self, b1, b2, b3):
        x = b1 + b2
        y = b2 + b3
        self.__plot__(self)
    # some attributes
    # some methods

    def __plot__(self, parent):
        class plot_fns:
            # plot functions
            def plot1(self):
               plt.plot(parent.x, parent.y)
        self.plot = plot_fns()

B = cls_B(b1, b2, b3)
B.plot.plot1()

Is there a better way to do this?

Note that dunder methods (starting and ending with __) are reserved for the language. You should not name __plot__ that, lest you'll provoke some naming conflict in some future Python version.

@deceze Class B is not inheriting from Class A, because they do not have all the same attributes. I have updated the question.

Then create a 3rd class from which both A and B inherit…? That's known as a mixin, if it just adds some methods.

To be true to what you are doing without repeating yourself, you can inherit from a SubPlot class that implements the subclass:
class SubPlot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__plot__(self)

    def __plot__(self, parent):
        class plot_fns:
            # plot functions
            def plot1(self):
                print("plotting", parent.x, parent.y)
        self.plot = plot_fns()


class PlotA(SubPlot):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class PlotB(SubPlot):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


PlotA(1, 2).plot.plot1()
PlotB(3, 4).plot.plot1()


you can have a class inherit from one (or more) other classes using
class PlotterClass:
    def plot1(self):
        ...

class MyClass(PlotterClass,MySuperClass2,...):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

instance = MyClass()
instance.plot1()

assuming of course one of the superclasses has the method plot
